# Patching SUPEE 6285 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6285

My store currently running on Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 and I've using PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-10-08-10-09.sh

What I've done:

1. SUPEE-5994 patch is installed as checked on app/etc/applied.patches.list
2. The problem seems to lie with the file errors/processor.php and I did a check for error/processor.php.rej, the file is not there.

Appreciate any help rendered. Thanks!

Chris

Below is the error while patching.

```
[vq3.phsserver.net:/home/fitnessa/public_html]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-10-08-10-09.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 460.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file errors/processor.php.rej
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: if you have previously applied patch
>   PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1, please revert it and apply
>   PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2. 
>   Make sure to install SUPEE-5994 patch first.

source: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.30314687.1010211015.1443184171#download1737